# Number counter changes quantities on +/- press in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In my android app with kotlin,I would like to know if there's a dependency as as the following picture below : the remove icon in the left side, the quantity in the center and the add icon in the right, a number counter changes quantities on +/- press
Or, should I create it by my self ?

[image]

Comment: Is this something to do with Android? Because at the moment it's not clear what this is to do with Kotlin

Comment: In my android App, I use a kotlin as language, I will edit my question to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

Try this  pretty  library (https://github.com/ashik94vc/ElegantNumberButton)

Comment: I try it, but the elegant number button is not showing

Comment: Can you share, how are you using it?